# openpyxl is deleting data off other sheets and not preserving external data references

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet (Excel 2013) that already had data, formulas, formatting, and links to some SharePoint lists that auto-update with employee names. I am trying to update some of the static data on a few of the sheets through openpyxl in `python 3.4`. The program runs fine but when I open the excel file things are deleted and external references are messed up (now just static values rather than linked to the SharePoint list). I could understand the tables getting messed up if I was editing them, but I am just changing the value of a cell on another tab. Thank you in advance for any assistance, as I have looked everywhere.

```
eodReport = openpyxl.load_workbook('End of Day Sales Report 3.0.xlsx')

overallSales = eodReport.get_sheet_by_name('Overall Sales')

overallSales['A1'] = 'test'

eodReport.save('test.xlsx')
```